# Node.js и MongoDB профилирование

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Какие на сегодняшний день существует бесплатные инструменты по профилированию `Node.js` + `MongoDb` кода?
Требуется наличие графического вывода результатов.
Например аналог профайлинга в платформе `Pycharm`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Устроят решения(плагины) как для платформ `JetBrains` так и любые другие модули.